# How to write bold italics in math mode in python (matplotlib)?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, math, latex

I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from latex import bm
plt.text(1, 1, "$\bm{q}$")
```

the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'bm'
```

When I use it without `from latex import bm` it gives nothing and the colors in file are strange (b is black)

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib knows how to render LaTeX by itself. You can just remove the `from latex import bm` line, as that's not what the latex package is for.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I editted my question for more information

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues here, one of which is simpler to fix than the other: the first issue is that the `"\b"` in your string literal will be interpreted as a Python-level string escape: `"\b"` is an ASCII backspace character, in the same way that `"\t"` is a tab character. You need to either escape the backslash so that it gets passed through to LaTeX, or use a raw string. So you need to replace `"$\bm{q}$"` with either `r"$\bm{q}$"` or `"$\\bm{q}$"`.

The second issue is that by default, matplotlib's math rendering uses the [`mathtext`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) library, which doesn't include support for the `"\bm"` control sequence. If you want to use LaTeX packages not included in `mathtext`, you can instruct matplotlib to use your local LaTeX installation to render mathematics, instead of using `mathtext`. You do that with, for example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

Then you need to make sure that the `bm` package is being used. To do that, you need to change the LaTeX preamble that matplotlib uses:

```
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{bm}']
```

This does of course mean that you need to have a working LaTeX installation on your machine, and key executables (like `latex`, `dvipng` and `kpsewhich`) need to be on your `PATH` so that matplotlib can find them.

Once you've done all that, the rendering should work.

Here's a complete self-contained example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{bm}']
plt.plot([0, 1, 2])
plt.text(1.5, 1, r"$\bm{testing}$")
plt.show()
```

And here's the image I see when I run the above code on my system (which is equipped with the standard [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) installation):

[image]